# Simular abrir Navegador para levantar un servidor web Archivo .bat

Tags: batch, .bat

Buenas noches como están?
Les comento, estoy armando un archivo .bat (soy nuevo en este tema) el cual lo que quiero que haga es desde el usuario de Windows bloqueado, quiero que simule todos los días a tal hora que entra a un navegador e ingrese a una ip (servidor) para que así el servidor empiece a levantar, cargue toda la base de datos que quede almacenada en cache y no tener que esperar 30 min a que levante cuando ingreso a trabajar.
El archivo .bat que estoy haciendo es el siguiente:

```
@echo off

set docTesting="http://192.168.251.122:90"
set rutaLog="C:\ParaLevantarDocTestingTodosLosDias"
set chrome="Chrome.exe"

start chrome %docTesting%

set anio=%date:~6,4%
set mes=%date:~3,2%
set dia=%date:~0,2%
set hora=%time:~0,2%
set hora=%hora: =0%
set minuto=%time:~3,2%
set segundo=%time:~6,2%

CD rutaLog

curl --head %docTesting% >> output.txt

echo ======================================== >> log.txt
echo FINALIZADO CON EXITO %anio%/%mes%/%dia% %hora%:%minuto%:%segundo% >> log.txt
echo ======================================== >> log.txt
```

Este archivo .bat lo tengo programado ya con el "Programador de tareas" de Windows para que lo ejecute todos los días a las 8:00 am
Hasta ahora si lo ejecuto de manera manual me abre en navegador y me crea los respetivos logs, el caso feliz, pero si lo programo a tal hora, lo único que me hace es agregarme la linea al log y no me levanta el servidor.

Me podrán ayudar con este problema? la otra solución que también puede ser, es, simular que el ingresa con el dominio y contraseña a el usuario de windows y ahí si abre el navegador, entra a la ip, espera un resultado y que luego cierre sesión de Windows nuevamente.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Sale algo relacionado en el visor de eventos? Algún error?

Comment: No me da ningún error el visor de eventos, se ejecuta el bat pero no esta levantando el servidor.

Comment: Lo otro que se me ocurre es que el programador de tareas esté ejecutando todo esto con un usuario diferente a tu usuario...

Comment: Lo que hice en el programador de tareas, es que como las credenciales son de un dominio, en vez de estar con mi usuario le puse que sea desde SYSTEM, ya que la pc cada ciertos días se reinicia automáticamente y no queda "vinculada" al usuario y en ese caso no sabría donde ejecutarlo el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Suena a que SYSTEM no debe tener mucha idea de qué es `chrome`. Por qué no pruebas arrancando la aplicación con la ruta completa?

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="http://192.168.251.122:90"
```

Fuente: [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161560/236345)

Comment: Probe, y tampoco no hay caso, el sistema no esta sabiendo que hacer, osea creo que esta omitiendo el paso start por esta la PC bloqueada, si lo hago con la pc desbloqueada de forma manual funciona.

Comment: Me retracto, estaba programandolo mal, ahora si me levanta el navegador con la maquina bloqueada, pero no me genera archivo txt como que finalizo bien. Que puede ser?